# Not able to open previously installed build from TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

I have a build installed from TestFlight on ios device. I am not able to open this app. I have not accepted the invite for next version. Does INSTALLED build get invalidate after new version is released from TestFlight? What is the behaviour for Internal and external testers in this case?

Answer (score 0):

We have had a number of our app's TestFlight users report that after updating iOS they can't open the app. We had to send them a new build to get things working.